# What are Apple iCloud default calendars?

Tags: icloud, caldav

I am accessing Apple iCloud Calendars using CalDav. Currently I have 4 calendars in my account: Home, Work, Test cal 1, Test cal 2. The first two seems to be created by default, the other two are test ones.

However when I list calendars of my principal, I get 8 different Calendars:

`/calendars/64E6F061-DE12-4D6F-B7D4-5DFDE53C800C/` is my Test Cal 1

`/calendars/A1FBED21-5ED1-4BEF-8C4F-88A0D425BB7A/` is my Test Cal 2

`/calendars/home/` Home Calendar, believe this is main calendar

`/2003926771/calendars/work/` Work Calendar

But I am not sure about the purpose of these other calendars:

`/calendars/inbox/`

`/calendars/notification/`

`/calendars/tasks/`

`/calendars/outbox/`

Could try to guess from their names, but that leads to more questions. `tasks`, as an example, could mean VTODOs are managed in this calendar, but would that mean VTODOs are not listed in any other calendar?

Anyway, main question is anyone knows the purpose of each of those (default?) iCloud calendars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: A CalDAV server can contain arbitrary CalDAV collections, not just calendars. E.g. it is not quite uncommon that the server also contains CardDAV collections (aka addressbooks) or even collections used for file storage. You can figure out the type of a WebDAV collection by looking at its `{DAV:}resourcetype` property. For CalDAV calendars (a collection containing actual iCalendar objects), that will be [`{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav}calendar`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-4.2).

#### /calendars/tasks

> tasks, as an example, could mean VTODOs are managed in this calendar

Correct. The collection will have the `{urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav}calendar` resourcetype mentioned above.
What types of iCalendar entities a collection can contain is then determined by the [`{urn:item:params:xml:ns:caldav}supported-calendar-component-set`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-5.2.3) property, e.g.:

```
<supported-calendar-component-set xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
  <comp name="VTODO"/>
</supported-calendar-component-set>
```

... in the case of the tasks collection.

You use the same property to specify the type of calendar when creating new collections on the server.

> but would that mean VTODOs are not listed in any other calendar

CalDAV technically supports both styles, 'hybrid' calendars which can contain todos and events, and single-type calendars. 'hybrid' calendars will contain multiple `comp` elements in the `supported-calendar-component-set`. The iCloud server can do both styles.

Which style is preferred is largely a matter of taste. In the Apple world single-type calendars are the default, in part because Reminders and Calendar are distinct applications on iOS and on macOS. (the original MacOSX iCal app was hybrid). Also, Outlook only really supports single-type calendars.

Long story short: I would recommend to keep them distinct to avoid weird things happening :-)

#### /calendars/outbox/

The [outbox](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638#section-2.1) is a legacy thing to support scheduling. A client would put meeting requests and such into this collection, and then server would fan them out on the clients behalf.

iCloud now acts as a [auto-scheduling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638) CalDAV server. In short this means that if you put a VEVENT containing ATTENDEEs etc into an iCloud calendar, it will automatically do the iTIP interactions w/ those ATTENDEEs.

Summary: just skip/ignore this.

#### /calendars/inbox/

This is the peer to `outbox`, but unlike `outbox` the [`inbox`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638#section-2.2) is still being used. When people invite you to a meeting/event, the `inbox` will contain the meeting request(s) sent by the client.

With [auto-scheduling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638) CalDAV servers this primarily serves as a way to notify the user of being invited, that is, it'll pop up in the 'Inbox' tab of the iOS Calendar, or in the notification popup on macOS Calendar.
Note that with an auto-scheduling server, the server *also* updates or creates matching records in the users calendars. That is, for each item in the inbox you'll find another item with the same UID in a regular calendar (unless it is a cancellation of course).

In non-autoscheduling servers with inbox support, the client is technically supposed to take the iTIP item out of the Inbox and put that into a calendar. But I don't think any client still supports this operation and I don't know servers which have an Inbox but are not auto-scheduling.

Summary: This collections contain notifications about inbox invites (as iTIP objects).

#### /calendars/notification/

This is similar to the Inbox, it is a collection that contains non-iTIP notifications. Its primary use is for CalDAV [shared calendars](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/master/doc/Extensions/caldav-sharing.txt). If you are invited to a calendar, this collection will contain the invitation.

Comment: Many thanks @hnh. Such a detailed answer. Unfortunately I don't have reputation enough to UP as useful answer. It helped me to understand more of CalDav basics, making it easier to read and understand related RFCs. Reading those when starting to deal with CalDav can be a bit cumbersome.